# ¿Por que mi script sencillo con cron no guarda la salida en otro archivo usando ">"?

Tags: script, cron

Buenos días:

Tengo un script llamado hello_script.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Hello World"
```

Hice también un crontab que lo manda ejecutar cada 1 minuto y manda la salida a un archivo llamado "simon"

```
*/1 * * * * * ./hello_script.sh>simon
```

El demonio cron si está funcionando presuntamente por que veo que el archivo simon si va cambiando de fecha de modificación automáticamente cada minuto, pero el detalle es que cuando lo abro para ver el texto que contiene veo que no tiene nada de nada. Ya hice otros intentos con comandos simples como poner un comando "ls" en el script pero tampoco me guarda nada en el archivo simon, algo estoy haciendo mal pero no se que es. ¿Alguna orientación? Gracias

Comment: Le asignaste permiso de ejecución al script mediante ``chmod +x`` , además tu script lo único que hace es mostar por pantalla "Hello World", no debería cambiar?

Comment: Si si lo he hecho eso de asignar permisos de ejecución pero el resultado es igual. Mi script solo manda un hello world por que solo es para aprender a hacerlo, no necesito que haga cosas más complicadas por el momento. Si así tengo problemas imagínate si le pongo más cosas.